# Running a method on browser close tab or browser exit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-browser, dom-events

Is there an action handler I can use in Javascript+Angular+JQuery that makes it possible to schedule a method to be executed just before a tab is closed in the web browser?

By close I mean quitting the browser or closing the tab or crashing or anything...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect browser or tab closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you just bind the the `beforeunload`  on the window object.

```
angular.element($window).bind("beforeunload", exitHandler)
```